# C# import certificate and key (PFX) into CNG/KSP

Tags: c#, windows, certificate, x509certificate, pkcs#12

I'm trying to import a certificate/key (PFX) into Windows Certificate Store, using a KSP to store the key. The idea behind that is to be able to use a custom KSP, even if for now i'm simply using the default one.

Storing the key into the KSP using CNG is somehow the "easy" part, and here's the code that works for me:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"c:\temp\test.pfx", "test123", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
RSACng rsaCNG = new RSACng();
rsaCNG.FromXmlString(cert.GetRSAPrivateKey().ToXmlString(true));
var keyData = rsaCNG.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.GenericPrivateBlob);
var keyParams = new CngKeyCreationParameters
{
    ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.None,
    KeyCreationOptions = CngKeyCreationOptions.MachineKey,
    Provider = CngProvider.MicrosoftSoftwareKeyStorageProvider
};
keyParams.Parameters.Add(new CngProperty(CngKeyBlobFormat.GenericPrivateBlob.Format, keyData, CngPropertyOptions.None));
var key = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.Rsa, "testKey", keyParams);
```

However, i'm then unable to associate this key with the certificate, in order to store the certificate correctly into the Windows store. The following code:

```
rsaCNG = new RSACng(key);
X509Certificate2 certOnly = new X509Certificate2(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert));
certOnly.PrivateKey = rsaCNG;
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
store.Add(certOnly);
store.Close();
```

fails with exception: `Only asymmetric keys that implement ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm are supported.` at line `certOnly.PrivateKey = rsaCNG`.

Does anybody know how to do it right? I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.2, and would like to avoid P/Invoke if possible. And i can upgrade to .NET Framework 4.7.X if necessary, though the code raises the same error in 4.7.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `CopyWithPrivateKey` extension method from 4.7.2, it understands both CAPI and CNG keys.

```
// certWithKey understands it has a persisted key reference if rsaCNG's key is
// a named key, so adding it to the store and reading it back will work.
X509Certificate2 certWithKey = certOnly.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsaCNG);
...
store.Add(certWithKey);
...
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working with the default KSP (Software). However, when i'm trying another KSP (for instance the Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider), your line fails with `Keyset does not exist`(HRESULT 2146893802).

Comment: @PKIGuy Strange.  If you can give repro steps please [report a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49135105/6535399).

Comment: sure: in my original code, replace CngProvider.MicrosoftSoftwareKeyStorageProvider by new CngProvider("Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider"), and then use your code. You need a working TPM on your machine of course.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the resulting app is launched from a cmd with elevated privileges

Comment: BTW, changing `ExportPolicy` to `CngExportPolicies.AllowArchiving` (which can make a lot of sense for this KSP), changes the error to `The provided key does not match the public key for this certificate` (HRESULT -2147024809).

Comment: Also note that the "MachineKey" flag is lost once the key is imported! However, it is indeed imported in machine context, as shown by `certutil -key`.

Comment: I found out that the `Keyset does not exist` only appears for the TPM KSP when using the MachineKey flag. The cause seems to be a bug in CopyWithPrivateKey, which searches for a user key and not a machine key. If a user key with the same name exists, the user key will be linked to the certificate in the machine store!

Comment: With above code I see error: 
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The certificate already has an associated private key.'

Answer (score 0):

While bartonjs' answer works well for the Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider, it fails for the Microsoft Platform Key Storage Provider and machine keys due to [a bug in the KSP or .NET](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/45759) that PKI Guy has already pointed at (the imported key has IsMachineKey false).

There is a workaround that works for the Platform Key Storage Provider even for machine keys: https://github.com/glueckkanja-pki/TPMImport